# What to use when creating reporting tables at Sql Server 2008 as a scheduled task

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I want to create database tables for my reporting purposes.As i am seperating my reporting system from the transactional system.

I will create tables like

- .report_company_id_12_unique_views (use case 1)
- .report_company_id_18_unique_views
- .report_adserver_id_22_unique_counts (use case 2)
- .report_adserver_id_44_unique_counts...so on

We have 50+ reporting use-cases and most tables hold no more than 200 rows and we have to deal with every use case differently as they are all unique.

But i will have around 8.000 tables for these purposes.

8.000 tables *don't sound so cool* but i wanna use the reporting db for **fast access**.

> > > > this is db is designed just for a datastore....Even there are no primary
> > > >         keys in tables....all the purpose is read only access the data which is extracted from **n* million row tables**.Think it as denormalized version of the real db for reporting.We create tables ,insert data and next schedule we drop and insert data again.

My question is which tool should i use for this scheduled task ?

- 1.SQL Agent(where i have to write cursors do everything in process)
- 2.Windows task library where i can call my code and let the out of process classes do the job.
- 3.???? ( some other choice )

-nosql solutions are not accepted. :(

**my requirements to meet**

- 1.Easy to debug ( relatively )
- 2.Easy to extend ( relatively )
- 3.Easy to deploy ( absolutely )

Comment: If you have 8,000 tables you're doing it wrong. Your table names suggest you're creating one for each ID. Why?

Comment: 8,000 tables? Are you insane!!!!

Comment: i even hate to write 8.000 :D . this is db is designed just for a datastore....there are no primary keys in tables....all the purpose is read only

Comment: I agree, the first response to this should be "refactor so you're not using 8000 tables". You can do fast, read-only access with primary keys. There's no need for this kind of table bloat - if you're going to do something like this that's a basic key-value store, look into a NoSQL alternative.

Comment: NoSQL alternatives :( not permited in our enviroment.

Comment: i wished we could use no sql... :(

Comment: Without clustered indexes (probably what you mean by primary key) you cannot select a subset of the data so you actually need that many tables. *With* clustered indexes you can select a subset and don't need tables. Why don't you want to use "primary keys"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

antinescience

> I agree, the first response to this should be "refactor so you're not
>   using 8000 tables". You can do fast, read-only access with primary
>   keys. There's no need for this kind of table bloat - if you're going
>   to do something like this that's a basic key-value store, look into a
>   NoSQL alternative. – antinescience 17 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is to use SQL Server Agent.  It is integrated with SQL Server and gives you the basic functionality you need to accomplish the task.  There isn't any reason (from your question) for using other software.

That said, there are some short-comings, particularly (in my opinion) with regards to error handling and notifications.

You don't describe the process for creating each table.  If it is as simple as selecting from a view, then you can set up a reporting table and loop through that table for the final reports.

As with the comments, I think that 8,000 tables suggests a problem with the data model.  You should be able to combine like reports into a single table (you mention 50, which suggests 50 tables) and use other mechanisms for separating out the reports for each company/server.  For instance, if they are accessing the "tables" directly, then use user-defined table functions or views, rather than a proliferation of tables.

Comment: ok i think i gave up the idea 8000 tables. Maybe i should use Json and store the table data inside one table. At the end of the day i need a key value store.it sucks that i cant use nosql system....(people are afraid not beign able to see their data when not in sql server )

Comment: by doing so i will become less arrogant and accept the nosql idea. Coloumns in the table (id,JsonData(nvarchar(max)),companyid,userid,reportname,createdate)